# Ionic 2 how to make InAppBrowser and other plugins work when running in a browser

Tags: api, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a app in Ionic 2, wich consumes a web api from an existing site. To use this API i have to make athenticate in it in the following way (Similar to facebook login):

- I call the api login page in a InAppBrowser component, sending the proper keys and a return URL.
- the user types the login and password in the form displayed, the API will validate it and authenticate it.
- The API calls the return URL passing the authorization token.
- I 'hijack' this redirect to the return url in the InAppBrowser 'loadstart' event, and extract and store the authorization token.
- In the following calls to the API, i send the authorization token in the header.

This is all working fine in the emulator, but it doesn't work in the browser (with ionic serve), because when i call InAppBrowser it actually calls window.open, and the events doesnt work. I can't detect the redirect action made in the opened window.

I'd like to make this work in the browser since its better to debug the application there. My first thought was to send "http://localhost:8001" as the return url, but I couldn't find a way to catch the token parameter in the ionic application.

Does anyone know how I can catch this parameter or any other way to make this login work in the browser? It is for development and debug purposes only, so strict security is not a issue  (I can comment out any unsecure code in the production version).

---

Edit: Hayden Braxton answer didn't solve my problem, but since it was because of something exclusively to my app, and it could really help someone who wants to make plugins work, I'll keep it as the selected answer.

Besides that, I'll share the solution I found to my problem in case it could help anyone. It was simple, actually:

- I pass "http://localhost:8001" as the api return_uri parameter
- the api will, after checking the login and password, redirect to http://localhost:8001?token=MY_AUTH_TOKEN.
- This will reload the application and call login page again.
- In the login page i call `this.platform.getQueryParam("token");` to get the token.

Comment: inAppBrowser is a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). cordova plugins are not loaded in ionic serve..

Comment: I know that, I'm searching for an alternative to make the login work in ionic serve.

Comment: So did my solution solve your problem, or naw? If it did, it'd be great if you could mark it is the solution, if not, please post additional details that would help us reach a solution.

Comment: For the sake of the community, you might also want to consider editing the title of your question. Correct me if I'm wrong, but on a larger scale, it seems your question is more about getting ionic pluggins to work when running in the browser, and Your login issue seems to be a side effect of this larger problem. Others will have the same question about getting the pluggins to work, all with different applications and needs.

Comment: I used this title because my objective wasn't making the plugin work, was making the login work , with or without the plugin, but I understand the new title would help other people based on the answer, so I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
"browser": "ionic-app-scripts serve --iscordovaserve --sourceMap source-map  --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build",
```

to the script section of your package.json. Then instead of doing ionic serve, instead run

```
npm run browser
```

We use ionic2 to develop our apps where I work, and this is what we figured out after some research.

Before using this, you need to have the browser platform added. You can accomplish this with the following:

```
ionic add platform browser
```

If the browser platform is already added, delete the browser directory from your platforms directory and then run the add platform command, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: What will this configuration do?

Comment: Pretty much it let's you use cordova pluggins when you're running your app locally for development. We're currently on ionic-app-script 1.1.3 and it works for us. We make use of InAppBrowser in our apps at work, and starting the app locally with the above command let's us use InAppBrowser as well as other pluggins.

Comment: I honestly can't explain to you the details of what's happening under the hood. The ionic cli and ionic-app-scripts are not well-documented and have had periods of uncertainty in prior versions. As of 1.1.3 this works though. My boss spent some time picking through their source code and came up with this. So it's the command I use whenever I'm running ionic apps localy and it let's us use cordova pluggins.

Comment: interesting.. do you need browser platform added for this?

Comment: yeah good question. You do need to have the browser platform added.

Comment: Thanks, Hayden, that seems to have solved the issue, just a small correction, I had to use `ionic platform add browser` instead of `ionic add platform browser`. I also having an error message: `Refused to display "http://myurl" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`. I`m going to investigate it and post the results here.